# Peneus River (Metamorphoses 1.567–572)

Tags: classical-latin, translation-check, genitive, ovidius, metamorphoses

I just worked on translating a passage that was very difficult for me, and not without a lot of help from online resources. Here is the passage below:

> Est nemus Haemoniae, praerupta quod undique claudit
>   silva: vocant Tempe. Per quae Peneus ab imo
>   effusus Pindo spumosis volvitur undis,
>   deiectuque gravi tenues agitantia fumos
>   nubila conducit summisque adspergine silvis
>   inpluit et sonitu plus quam vicina fatigat.

My English translation:

> There is a grove in Thessaly, which an abrupt wood encloses on every
>   side: they call it Tempe. Through which Peneus poured out from the
>   foot of Pindus is rolled out in frothy waves, and by its heavy
>   downfall gathers mists driving thin fumes, and rains on the tops of
>   woods with its spray, and vexes more than the vicinity with its sound.

---

In general, what are the strengths and weaknesses of this translation? In particular, I have a few questions.

1. The beginning clause uses the genitive to communicate location, i.e., "There is a grove in Thessaly". Is this a common use of the genitive? How would we qualify this use?
2. Would you translate *tenues fumos* as thin fumes? I have a hard time seeing how a river creates "thin fumes", but the online resource I was using translated the phrase that way.
3. I had a hard time translating the final clause: *and vexes more than the vicinity with its sound*. Do you think I arrived at a good translation? I happen to like this translation, so I would be happy to keep it if it works.

I appreciate any feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ad 1: I would not be surprised if it were a genitive: Tempe as a grove of Thessaly sound unremarkable enough. However, there are two other options. The first is a locative: there is a grove in Thessaly. That would be semantically good, but the locative is not normally used with regions in prose (rather than with cities and small islands). Lastly, it could be a possessive dative: nemus est Haemoniae = "there is a grove to Thessaly" = "Thessaly has a grove". This construction is common.

Ad 2: that sounds OK; what it makes me think of is thin vapours of splashing water. The word "fume" is perhaps a bit misleading in English, because it's not normally used for mere water mists or vapours, I believe. Tenuis can mean thin in most senses, like delicate, subtle, but also just any opposite of thick. You could also translate it as *fine* in the context of mist.

Ad 3: sounds good. You seem to have captured both the construction and its intention very well. What did you think might be wrong with it?

Comment: I think 1 is definitely a genitive, specifically a "geographic" or "chorographic" genitive as this usage is sometimes known.